# Display only specific statistics (Median, mean, std, var, min val,max val, quantiles) with one command. No extra statistics

Tags: r

Display only the specific statistics median, mean, standard deviation, variance,
inter quartile range, min value, max value and
the first and the third quartile for the variables
of the dataframe.

I tried the following command but its not showing the median,min,max and variance.

```
library("RcmdrMisc")

numSummary(df[,c('v1','v2'),drop=FALSE], statistics=c("median",mean","sd","var","IQR",
                  "min","max","quantiles"), quantiles
           =c(0,.25,.5,.75,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
For  `numSummary` type `?numSummary` in your console then you get this example:

```
if (require("car")){
    data(Prestige)
    Prestige[1, "income"] <- NA
    print(numSummary(Prestige[,c("income", "education")], 
        statistics=c("mean", "sd", "quantiles", "cv", "skewness", "kurtosis")))
    print(numSummary(Prestige[,c("income", "education")], groups=Prestige$type))
    remove(Prestige)
}
```

Output:

```
                mean          sd        cv  skewness   kurtosis     0%      25%     50%       75%     100%   n NA
income    6742.92079 4230.450564 0.6273914 2.2565718  7.2046866 611.00 4075.000 5902.00 8131.0000 25879.00 101  1
education   10.73804    2.728444 0.2540915 0.3345254 -0.9782158   6.38    8.445   10.54   12.6475    15.97 102  0

Variable: income 
          mean       sd     IQR   0%     25%    50%      75%  100%  n NA
bc    5374.136 2004.330 2892.75 1656 3836.75 5216.5  6729.50  8895 44  0
prof 10499.733 5505.145 5687.50 4614 6516.75 8645.0 12204.25 25879 30  1
wc    5052.304 1944.325 3175.50 2448 3450.00 4741.0  6625.50  8780 23  0

Variable: education 
          mean        sd    IQR    0%    25%   50%     75%  100%  n NA
bc    8.359318 1.1648343 1.3525  6.38  7.570  8.35  8.9225 10.93 44  0
prof 14.084194 1.3940248 2.2100 11.09 12.940 14.44 15.1500 15.97 31  0
wc   11.021739 0.9233076 0.8850  9.17 10.575 11.13 11.4600 12.79 23  0
```

**First answer: alternatives:**
You could use `stat.desc` from `pastecs` package:
or `summary` or `library(Hmisc) Hmisc::describe(mtcars)`

Here an example with `pastecs`

```
#install.packages("pastecs")
library(pastecs)
stat.desc(mtcars)
```

Output:

```
                     mpg         cyl         disp           hp         drat          wt        qsec          vs
nbr.val       32.0000000  32.0000000 3.200000e+01   32.0000000  32.00000000  32.0000000  32.0000000 32.00000000
nbr.null       0.0000000   0.0000000 0.000000e+00    0.0000000   0.00000000   0.0000000   0.0000000 18.00000000
nbr.na         0.0000000   0.0000000 0.000000e+00    0.0000000   0.00000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  0.00000000
min           10.4000000   4.0000000 7.110000e+01   52.0000000   2.76000000   1.5130000  14.5000000  0.00000000
max           33.9000000   8.0000000 4.720000e+02  335.0000000   4.93000000   5.4240000  22.9000000  1.00000000
range         23.5000000   4.0000000 4.009000e+02  283.0000000   2.17000000   3.9110000   8.4000000  1.00000000
sum          642.9000000 198.0000000 7.383100e+03 4694.0000000 115.09000000 102.9520000 571.1600000 14.00000000
median        19.2000000   6.0000000 1.963000e+02  123.0000000   3.69500000   3.3250000  17.7100000  0.00000000
mean          20.0906250   6.1875000 2.307219e+02  146.6875000   3.59656250   3.2172500  17.8487500  0.43750000
SE.mean        1.0654240   0.3157093 2.190947e+01   12.1203173   0.09451874   0.1729685   0.3158899  0.08909831
CI.mean.0.95   2.1729465   0.6438934 4.468466e+01   24.7195501   0.19277224   0.3527715   0.6442617  0.18171719
var           36.3241028   3.1895161 1.536080e+04 4700.8669355   0.28588135   0.9573790   3.1931661  0.25403226
std.dev        6.0269481   1.7859216 1.239387e+02   68.5628685   0.53467874   0.9784574   1.7869432  0.50401613
coef.var       0.2999881   0.2886338 5.371779e-01    0.4674077   0.14866382   0.3041285   0.1001159  1.15203687
                      am        gear       carb type
nbr.val      32.00000000  32.0000000 32.0000000   NA
nbr.null     19.00000000   0.0000000  0.0000000   NA
nbr.na        0.00000000   0.0000000  0.0000000   NA
min           0.00000000   3.0000000  1.0000000   NA
max           1.00000000   5.0000000  8.0000000   NA
range         1.00000000   2.0000000  7.0000000   NA
sum          13.00000000 118.0000000 90.0000000   NA
median        0.00000000   4.0000000  2.0000000   NA
mean          0.40625000   3.6875000  2.8125000   NA
SE.mean       0.08820997   0.1304266  0.2855297   NA
CI.mean.0.95  0.17990541   0.2660067  0.5823417   NA
var           0.24899194   0.5443548  2.6088710   NA
std.dev       0.49899092   0.7378041  1.6152000   NA
coef.var      1.22828533   0.2000825  0.5742933   NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I already checked all these functions. These functions show the extra statistics which I don't need. I only need median, mean, standard deviation, variance, inter quartile range, the smallest value, largest value and the first and the third quartile for the variables.

Comment: could you please `dput()` your data. Then it is much easier to help. Therefore people are downvoting your fquestion. See here how to ask on stackoverflow: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>